# Search CSV if list element is present then delete

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and trying to import 2 csv files using `csv.reader` then comparing to see if elements from one are present in the other, and if so deleting that entire row.

I have found other questions to similar problems that suggest list comprehension is the way to go but when I do the loop to check if the `appList` exists in `machine` the result I get is empty brackets like thus [].

My code so far is:

```
import csv

appList = csv.reader(open('applist.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
appList = list(appList)

machine = csv.reader(open('machine.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
machine = list(machine)

for app in appList:
     machine = [app for app in machine if app not in machine]
     print(machine)
```

The applist.csv looks like this (its a list of apps on a macOS standard build)

```
Adobe Creative Cloud for Enterprise
Adobe Acrobat DC Professional
Adobe Bridge CC
Adobe Extension Manager CC
Adobe Illustrator CC 2015
Adobe InDesign CC 2015
Adobe Photoshop CC 2015
Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015
AirPort Utility 6
App Store
Automator 2
[...]
```

The machine.csv looks like this...

```
"Application name";"Metric";"Last used";"Requirement";"Entitlement state";"Remark"
"Adobe Creative Cloud for Enterprise (Mac)";"Installations";"2018-03-28T10:45:00+01:00";"1";"Not covered";""
"Adobe Acrobat DC Professional (Mac)";"Installations";"2018-03-22T17:08:00+00:00";"0";"No requirement";"Installation included in software bundle"
"Adobe Bridge CC (Mac)";"No license required";"2018-03-12T13:45:00+00:00";"";"";"Installation included in software bundle"
"Adobe Extension Manager CC (Mac)";"No license required";"";"";"";"Installation included in software bundle"
"Adobe Illustrator CC 2015 (Mac)";"Installations";"2018-03-12T13:41:00+00:00";"0";"No requirement";"Installation included in software bundle"
```

**[Updated to add]**

My code currently:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os
import csv

def csv_reader(machine_dir, machine):
    mach_list = list(csv.reader(open(machine_dir + "/" + machine, encoding="ISO-8859-1"), delimiter=";"))
    return mach_list

def main():
    # Get the paths to the csv files
    csvFile = input("drop the app list csv here: ")
    machine_dir = input("drop the machines csv folder here: ")

    # Import appList csv
    app_list = list(csv.reader(open(csvFile, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")))

    # Get list of machine csv
    machines = os.listdir(machine_dir)

    for machine in machines:
        machine_list = csv_reader(machine_dir, machine)

        new_machine = [app for app in app_list if app not in machine_list]

        print(new_machine)



if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I'm currently testing it on one machine csv file and the return result is not what's left after subtracting `app_list` from `machine_list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a conventional loop, then doing a list comprehension, which I don't think is what you need.

In your list comprehension you are looping through values in `machine` and then appending values to the list if the values are *not* in `machine`. So your logic is a bit off. You actually need to loop through the values of `appList` in your list comprehension and see whether they appear in the list `machine`:

```
import csv

appList = csv.reader(open('applist.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
appList = list(appList)

machine = csv.reader(open('machine.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
machine = list(machine)

new_machine = [app for app in appList if app not in machine]
```

**Edit:**

When opening your files, if you inspect them they are nested lists. One solution may be to flatten the lists, then use the same list comprehension:

```
import csv

appList = csv.reader(open('applist.csv'))
appList = list(appList)

machine = csv.reader(open('machine.csv'))
machine = list(machine)

# Flatten both appList and machine
flat_appList = [item for sublist in appList for item in sublist]
flat_machine = [item for sublist in machine for item in sublist]

new_machine = [app for app in flat_machine if app not in flat_appList]
```

Note: *be careful* - In the example csv files appList.csv contains e.g. `Adobe Creative Cloud for Enterprise` which is **not** the same as what is included in your machine.csv `Adobe Creative Cloud for Enterprise (Mac)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wasnt quite grasping the logic in the query!

Comment: @zanf No problem :-). If an answer worked for you then don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it

Comment: I'm finding that the `new_machine` is the same as `appList`, not what's left over from removing anything that's in `appList` from `machine`

Comment: @zanf Hmm yes you're right. The problem is because there are lots of nested lists. I'll update my answer soon

Comment: I'll update the question with the code I have as I tried yours and @L.MacKenzie's solutions

Comment: @zanf I've updated the answer, see if that helps you

Comment: I had wondered about if it was a strict comparison or whether it was more lax (*if most of this matches that*).

Comment: As a result, I have updated the app_list so that it has what could potentially be the full string to match.

Comment: I still think this is giving me what's in `app_list` that's not in `machine` whereas I want what's left in `machine` after any duplicates from`app_list` have been removed.

Comment: You can just change round the lists in the list comprehension, ive edited the answer. The result would still be a flat list of course. If you want to keep the original structure then you might have to have an extra loop in there too

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `pandas` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html) (assuming that there are no duplicate lines within each file that you want to keep).

```
import pandas

app = pandas.read_csv('applist.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
machine = pandas.read_csv('machine.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

# Combine both dataframes into one
dataframe = app.append(machine, ignore_index=True)

# Only keep the first of each set of duplicates
# This should give us the machine list (without any of the lines
# duplicated in the applist) plus the full applist
dataframe.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
# Now add the applist again
dataframe = dataframe.append(app, ingore_index=True)
# Now drop all the duplicates
# (since the applist was added again, this should drop the entire applist)
dataframe.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Now 'dataframe' should be the machine list without any lines from applist
```

If these files are relatively small, then using a loop will be about the same time as using pandas, but if these files large pandas should be significantly faster.

Comment: As a relative noob, what would be considered 'large files' for use with `pandas`?

Comment: I've been playing around with `pandas` and this method just merges them into a single dataframe then removes the duplicates.

It's not a direct comparison of list A with list B and if an entry in list A occurs in list B it is removed from list B

Comment: I believe I must have misread your question originally. I updated my answer to use a slightly more complicated method of removing all the duplicates and only leaving the machine list without any of the applist. Also, I use `pandas` on 1-50 MB files, but it is probably still faster than looping through lists on files smaller than 1 MB.